# Shuffling cards and assigning them to user and computer in android development

Tags: android

I am creating a basic top trumps app in android development. I only need 6 top trumps card which have been made by using a database. I already have the code for this and have successfully created the cards.

I am stuck on this bit

When the user selects Play you should randomly assign half of the cards in the database to the human player, and half of the cards to the computer.

And was wondering if anyone had any ideas on how to do this? Thanks everyone.

**UPDATE**

I have tried doing this

```
ArrayList<Integer> cards = new ArrayList<Integer>();
for(int i=1;i<=6;i++)
{
this.cards.add(i);
}
Collections.shuffle(this.cards);
```

To shuffle the cards but I'm unsure on how to assign the computer and user the cards.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you are aiming for here, but would something like this do (after you have shuffled):

```
ArrayList<Integer> playerCards = new ArrayList<Integer>(cards.subList(0,2));    
ArrayList<Integer> computerCards = new ArrayList<Integer>(cards.subList(3,5));
```

Of course, you should use variables instead of constants everywhere, but you get the idea.

Comment: Ahh I see, I think I get it now! Will try and implement this, thank you!

Comment: Abigail, if you accept an answer, people will be more likely to answer your questions in the future.

Comment: Sorry haven't logged on for ages, done that now. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 1):

I am not an android programmer, but once long ago I realized the way to deal shuffled cards is to store the cards in an array or whatever in their natural order rather than a shuffled order -- for regular poker cards, 2-spades to A-spades, then 2-clubs to A-clubs, etc.  Then, instead of dealing cards in-order from the shuffled deck, deal the cards by random draw from the unshuffled deck.  You card elements need a "used" setting or value so they don't get reused or used twice.  Saves LOADS of time doing the shuffle.  In your case you on;y need to draw three cards, then the other guy gets the rest.